# Unable to get marketing details from LinkedIn API

Tags: python, linkedin-api

When I trying to get analytics data from the API using below code, I am getting error

Same error comes in postman request as well

```
import requests
import os


BASE_URL = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCreativesV2'
token = "***"

headers = {'Authorization': "Bearer {}".format(token)}
auth_response = requests.get(BASE_URL, headers=headers)

print(auth_response.json())
```

Error

> ```
> {'serviceErrorCode': 0, 'message': 'Resource adCreativesV2 does not exist', 'status': 404}
> ```

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-creatives?view=li-lms-unversioned&tabs=http#get-a-creative), it seems like doing a GET at `/adCreativesV2/` by itself doesn't do anything, but you need to specify further path like `/adCreativesV2/{CREATIVE_ID}`, etc. I guess that this is the reason you get a 404, because it does not serve anything. See also the Sample Request code on that page I linked.